# Adding image to a UIButton in the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uibutton, user-experience

I have in my app a navigation bar that have 2 buttons, one at each side. This button are used to change some important aspects of the app, like servers and stuff.

When the server is offline or have any problems the user is asked to change this option.

What i want is: How can i append a image to a button to call the user's attention? Something like this:

[image]

But the problem is: i don't even know how to start looking for this, how can i do it?

Comment: You can create that image and change the button's image whenever that time comes.

Comment: Problem is the title of the button will change a lot, so i don't really want to rely on images that much, i want just to add the "alert" image to the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend adding a UILabel as a subview of the button instead of an image, that way you can programmatically change it by using NSNotificationCenter from anywhere in your app.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(updateButtonLabel:)
     name:@"UpdateButtonLabel" object:nil];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem]
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonMethods:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTintColor:[UIColor companyBlue]];
    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.buttonLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18,-7,18,18)];
    self.buttonLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.buttonLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor companyRed];
    self.buttonLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
    self.buttonLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 9;
    self.buttonLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.buttonLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.buttonLabel.text = @"!";

    [button addSubview:self.buttonLabel];
}

- (void)updateButtonLabel:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSString *labelString = notification.object;

   // Post a notification from any view controller with a string with no characters to hide the label:
    if (newString.length < 1)
    {
        self.buttonLabel.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.buttonLabel.text = labelString;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: the button is inside a navigation bar, wouldn't that make the button cut everything out of its boundaries? i will check this and get back as soon as i can

Comment: It should still work. The code I'm using above is actually a custom UIView for a UIBarButtonItem I made. See updated answer as well. You will need to play with the frame values manually for what you want to do and what looks best to you.

Comment: Don't forget the dealloc method. See above in my answer.

Comment: Thanks I don't really need the NSNotification because this is called from a public method, but it's nice to have it here, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

For this `initWithCustomView` will work this with this you can add `UIView` objects there

```
 -(void)setRightBarButton{
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35);
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonMethods:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button];
    }
```

Comment: sorry, the question is not about adding a ``UIButton`` to a ``UINavigationBar`` its about adding a ``view`` to a ``UIButton`` that already is at the ``UINavigationBar``